# Parallel processing threads on split in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to split an incoming exchange in route based on some logic. Every split part would connect to an ssh server in a bean.

```
from("seda:compression")
    .routeId("Compressor")
    .split(beanExpression(new InstanceListParser(), "process"))
    .parallelProcessing()
        .to("bean:compressorClient?method=compress(${header.remoteHost},${header.dataCenter})")
    .end();
```

But it seems a maximum of 10 processes are being run in parallel.

I added the following code to increase the size of thread pool factory, but this does not help.

```
ThreadPoolProfile poolProfile = new ThreadPoolProfile("masterPoolProfile");
poolProfile.setMaxPoolSize(100);
poolProfile.setMaxQueueSize(100);
poolProfile.setPoolSize(50);
poolProfile.setKeepAliveTime(1L);
poolProfile.setTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MINUTES);

ThreadPoolFactory poolFactory = new DefaultThreadPoolFactory();
poolFactory.newThreadPool(poolProfile, Executors.defaultThreadFactory());

getContext().getExecutorServiceManager().setThreadPoolFactory(poolFactory);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the splitter to use `masterPoolProfile` as the thread pool or configure the `masterPoolProfile` to be the default profile. The latter means all threads pools created using that API in Camel will use this profile as baseline.

Read more about this in the Camel docs: http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
ThreadPoolProfile poolProfile = new ThreadPoolProfile("masterPoolProfile");
poolProfile.setMaxPoolSize(100);
poolProfile.setMaxQueueSize(100);
poolProfile.setPoolSize(50);
poolProfile.setKeepAliveTime(1L);
poolProfile.setTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
getContext().getExecutorServiceManager().setDefaultThreadPoolProfile(poolProfile)
```